# Carousel images moving to incorrect places on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Really sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, I found a couple of similar threads and followed the advice on using position: absolute but still wasn't able to get it to work.

I'm new to web coding and I'm just trying to play around with building a few things and have gotten stuck with this.

Essentially I've created a carousel of images, you click the next arrow and it takes you to the next image with a fadeOut / fadeIn.

It works brilliantly for the first click but every transition after that my next image moves to the bottom of my div then pops back up in to place.

I think I have the container being position: relative and my images being position: absolute which if I've read correctly is the right way to do it.

Can anyone point out where this is going wrong?

I did a jsFiddle here -

https://jsfiddle.net/xf1h05q5/3/

The js is here:

```
 $('.arrow-next').click(function () {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();

    if(nextSlide.length === 0) {
        nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
        nextDot = $('.dot').first();
    };
                     currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');

});

$('.arrow-prev').click(function () {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot')
    var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

    if(prevSlide.length === 0) {
        prevSlide = $('.slide').last()
        prevDot = $('.dot').last()

    };

    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    prevDot.addClass('active-dot');


});
```

and the css for the slider:

```
.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 240px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
}

 .slide {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.active-slide {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
.slide .container img {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your slide class must have, absolute position, just add to your **.slide** :

```
position: absolute;
```

Because your slides in under slider, when hidden

Just look:

https://jsfiddle.net/RomanGroovyDev/xf1h05q5/6/

Comment: Thank you, I tried adding the position to the img class but can see now why it needed to go on the slide.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/xf1h05q5/5/)**

Use an anonymous `callback function` to add your `fadeIn`. In short, `fadeIn` next image only once the `active image` has been `fadeOut`. Something as below:

```
currentSlide.fadeOut(600,function(){
    //perform these things once fadeOut is done
    $(this).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
})
```

Your modified `JS` would be as below:

```
$('.arrow-next').click(function () {
   var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
   var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
   var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
   var nextDot = currentDot.next();
   if (nextSlide.length === 0) {
       nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
       nextDot = $('.dot').first();
   };
   currentSlide.fadeOut(600,function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active-slide');
        nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
   })
   currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
   nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
});

$('.arrow-prev').click(function () {
   var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
   var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();
   var currentDot = $('.active-dot')
   var prevDot = currentDot.prev();
   if (prevSlide.length === 0) {
       prevSlide = $('.slide').last()
       prevDot = $('.dot').last()
   };
   currentSlide.fadeOut(600,function(){
   $(this).removeClass('active-slide');
   prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
})
    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
});
```